# Save data from input only if it's in a right format

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

Currently I have two input fields. One for date and another for time. What I am trying to do is to prevent saving the default value of these fields, since now I am able to actually save the placeholders values and I want to be able to save something only if it's a date or hour.

Here is my html :

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="date" ">Date:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <input type="date" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>

  <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="text">Hour:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <select class="form-control" id="time">
            <option value="Time" class="">Time</option>
                        <option value="10am" class="">10:00-10:30</option>
                        <option value="1030am" class="">10:30-11:00</option>
                        <option value="11am" class="">11:00-11:30</option>
                        </select>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Please, help!

Comment: What does _prevent saving the default value of these fields_ actually mean? ... None of the above code show any default value

Answer (score 1):

For the date, just use something like this `<input type="date"/>` It's an input meant for dates.
For the time, just use `<input type="time"/>` You guessed it; it's an input meant for times.

To test if your date is valid, you can use

`if ( Object.prototype.toString.call(d) === "[object Date]" )`

I'm not so savvy on regular expressions, but there is a function [here](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/validate-date/) under the heading ***4. Modular checkTime() function*** that appears to use one for time validation.

You can do any formatting you need in JS, but this will ensure you get a valid date and time.

Answer (score 1):

Validating Date:
Isn't the default value undefined? If so, reject the date if the value submitted is undefined using javascript. More info [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp).

Validating time:
Are you trying to figure out if they selected a date and if the hour is comprised of two half hours? That is my understanding. 
First, allow them to pick more than one time:

`<select class="form-control" id="time" multiple>`

Secondly, use javascript to parse the values entered there and check that there are only two and that everything after the '-' of the one date matches everthing befire the '-' of the other date. For example:

Correct:

10:00-**10:30** and **10:30**-11:00

Incorrect:

10:00-**10:30** and **11:00**-11:30